# Web API - custom errors - early in pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, error-handling

Looking to return a custom error page, rather than a yellow screen, for errors in a WebApi project, that happen early in the pipeline.

I've replaced the default IExceptionHandler.

which handles more errors than Exception filters, which doesn't handle

- Error inside the exception filter
- Exception related to routing
- Error inside the Message Handlers class
- Error in Controller Constructor

However not all exceptions are handled by replacing the IExceptionHandler

E.g. if I throw an error in the Application_BeginRequest (just an example of an error occuring early in the pipeline), it doesn't get picked up by this, and I get a yellow screen. With custom errors turned on, it's a cut down yellow screen, but still a yellow screen.

How can I handle all errors (even this early in the pipeline), and return back a custom JSON error with the right response code, like is done when the custom Exception Handler does fire.

Some articles
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/exception-handling-in-asp-net-web-api/
https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/the-asp-net-web-api-exception-handling-pipeline-a-guided-tour/
https://www.jayway.com/2016/01/08/improving-error-handling-asp-net-web-api-2-1-owin/
(I'm not using OWIN, but included for reference)

I can catch the error in the Global.asax Application_Error event

Comment: I think you're trying to hard, if there's an error this early on then surely you written something wrong and the code would not be live. Happy to be wrong about that though

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to return json response in application_error method in global.asax with an empty object or have a parameter 0 etc.